# Select value from multiple checkboxes on button click?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
<td><p><input  class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" value="Cars.id"> </p> </td>
```

This is list of cars id with checkbox.

```
 <button (click)="duplicate()"><ion-icon name="color-wand"></ion-icon> </button>
```

on this button click i want to get value of all cars in my .ts file. here is the function in .ts

```
duplicate() {
    var checkedValue = document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox:checked');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get all values of checkbox, there are several ways are available in Angular. In this answer I'll show you without using any formArray. like this -

```
<div *ngFor="let Car of Cars">
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(Car.id, $event.target.checked)"> {{Car.email}}<br>
  </div>

<button (click)="duplicate()" >Get values </button> 
 ----------------------------
emailFormArray: Array<any> = [];
  Cars = [ 
    {email:"email1", id: 1},
    {email:"email2", id: 2},
    {email:"email3", id: 3},
    {email:"email4", id: 4}
  ];

  onChange(email:string, isChecked: boolean) {
      if(isChecked) {
        this.emailFormArray.push(email);
      } else {
        let index = this.emailFormArray.indexOf(email);
        this.emailFormArray.splice(index,1);
      }
  }

  duplicate() {
    console.log(this.emailFormArray);
  }
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-peevcc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)